# An encoded message for Nigel

Tags: cipher, story

Nigel came inside from his back garden carrying the peas he'd harvested, and dumped them onto the table to be sorted according to which were edible and which weren't. Just as he did so, he noticed a letter lying on the table, now mostly buried by the peas, in what looked like the handwriting of his colleague Richard. He scrabbled through the sour pods, picked up the cryptic missive, and read:

> 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128
>
> I1, Y1, O8, A5, R1, U6, V3, M4, D2, A4, S4, U3, E3, J1, E11, A13, M2, I3, A2, F3, I6, O5, W1, S4, Y3, A14, U4, S1, P1, A8, E6

**What does the message say?**

Comment: For readers: " I " is an uppercase i :)

Comment: Does solving this require a copy of the corpus alluded to in the story?

Comment: It is probably A1Z26 and the following number, then binary rotated, then ascii. I may be wrong as primary attempts went cuckoo.

Comment: @ArkaKarmarkar, there is a hint embedded in the question and it seems like the solution will have to have something to do with the thing hinted at. Yours doesn't, so I bet it isn't what RA'T has in mind.

Comment: @Sean Yes, and O is an uppercase o (not zero). Every pair is a capital letter followed by a number.

Comment: @Gareth The solution of the puzzle doesn't require any external sources which aren't readily available on the internet.

Comment: Thanks. (*Legally* available on the internet?) I had an "obvious" guess requiring only a small and rather well-known subset of the rather large external source, but that was instantly refuted on seeing V3 :-).

Comment: @Gareth Yes, legally available. And your guess may still be right, since V3 is something of a special case ;-)

Comment: Hmmmmmm. I'll have to think about that some more.

Comment: (The first and most obvious version of my guess seems also to be refuted by S4 but there are other versions one could try.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The bit in the text about

> scrabbling through the sour pods

is a hint that this has to do with

> Scrabble, and the so-called SOWPODS word list.

The list of powers of two indicates

> that we should consider two-letter words.

So we'll make use of

> the list of 2-letter words in SOWPODS in alphabetical order as found e.g. [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Official_English_Scrabble_2-letter_words).

Now we interpret each item in the message as follows:

> "I1" means "1st two-letter word beginning with I", "U6" means "6th two-letter word beginning with U". And then we take the *second* letter of each of these words.

So, e.g., we begin as follows:

> `I1 -> ID -> D`
>  `Y1 -> YA -> A`
>  `O8 -> ON -> N`

and eventually we get

> DANGER!MEETMEATTENBYTHETOWNHALL

where the "!" represents

> a word that doesn't exist (there are no 2-letter words in SOWPODS containing a V).

---

User IAmInPLS cunningly notes that

> Nigel and Richard are two names extracted from the full name [Nigel Richards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigel_Richards_(Scrabble_player)), who is the world's highest-rated Scrabble player.

Comment: Good job! FWIW, the V3 (as well as being a very evil distraction) was meant to be a dash, as in "not applicable".

Comment: I assumed it was something like that (once I got past thinking it just indicated I was barking up the wrong tree).

Comment: Wow! But how does the list of powers of two indicate.that the letter-number combos refer to two-letter words? I took it to be a hint that there might be some bitwise things going on.

Comment: @MOehm, I think the idea is to suggest that you use "the power of two". It seems pretty contrived to me and I confess I don't like it at all (sorry, Rand al'Thor) but I think that's what's going on.

Comment: (The list of powers of two was, so far as I know, in no way part of my thought processes when I first thought of looking at two-letter words. Though who knows what might have been going on unconsciously?)

Comment: Thank you for coming up with the solution. Now I can sleep peacefully :)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: As in "Use the power of your imagination"? Thanks for clarifying that. I'm not so fond of that, either, but the puzzle had already lost me when going into all the details of Scrabble except the scores on the tiles.

Comment: Yeah, that's the kind of thing.

Comment: @MOehm and Gareth: I needed to hint at "two" in some way without making it too obvious. I thought that listing some powers of two would put the idea of "two" into solvers' minds while also being something of a red herring. It also seems realistic: if Richard wants Nigel to understand the message but not some random spy, he needs to signify "two" in some way, so he scribbles down some powers of two at the top and hopes Nigel will understand. I'm surprised you object to *that* part of it and not the V3 bit, which really was quite evil :-)

Comment: Heh. It felt to me as if the 2-letter words were an obvious thing to try, and it didn't feel as if that was in any way informed by the powers of 2. That either means you got it exactly right (and planted the idea in my brain without my noticing) or, er, not. I would have objected louder to the V3 thing if it hadn't provoked you into basically confirming my theory about how the puzzle works :-).

Comment: @randal'thor: Well, the red herring worked for me, then. `:)` I couldn't have solved the puzzle anyway. I didn't see the Scrabble connection. When I learned about it in chat, I thought about letter scores and possible spatial arrangements. I've now learned from Wiki that knowing allowable two-letter words is a skill needed towards the endgame, so Scrabble players may see the conection. Two-letter words also make sense in the cipher: One letter is defined by means of another. Decoding is unambiguous, but encoding isn't, which prevents cryptogram attacks.

Comment: @randal'thor: So, good puzzle and good answer, but I really never play Scrabble, so this one was lost on me. (That's just an observation, not a criticism.)