# A lad named E. Mandala

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, palindrome

In a follow up from [yesterday](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68071/i-received-an-email-from-a-trusted-source-which-contains-flags-and-symbols), I was sent another email from the same source. The tile of the message was, "A lad named E. Mandala" which I've set the title of this puzzle to. Can you help me make sense of the message below? I noticed that all of his words are palindromes, but what do those numbers mean? How do they correlate to the encrypted message?

> I'm a fool; aloof am I
> In words, drown I
> Is it I? It is I!
>
> Name not one man.
> O, stone, be not so
> I did, did I?
>
> 33
> 99
> 313
> 585
> 717
> 7447
> +-+-+
>
> Dhmx Pau Eau Qutc, O zxayz znmz eua chxh mgrh zu joiovnhx znoy shyymlh yaiihyykarre. Vrhmyh yhtj  zcu natjxhj kuaxzhht ayj my yuut my vuyyogrh zu se chyzhxt atout miiuatz yu znmz o imt qhhv se iuatzxe ymkh kxus se hbor atirh mlmot. Eua corr gh iusvhtymzhj av zu kobh sorrout ayj.
> O thhj euax nhrv,
> Euax kxhotj,
> Mjhjmeu
> Vxotih uk Tolhxom

Hint:

> Since the message itself has been decoded, here is a hint on how to solve it. You should take +-+-+ literally.

Comment: Based on your comments to the answer provided, why *cipher* tag was applied to this?

Comment: I meant it to be enigmatic originally, though I'll add it in now.

Comment: **Was it a car or a cat I saw**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decode the letter as

> Dear Juo Yuo Konw, I trust that you were able to dicipher this message successfully. Please send two hundred fourteen usd as soon as possible to my western union account so that i can keep my country safe from my evil uncle again. You will be compensated up to five million usd. 
>  I need your help, 
>  Your freind, 
>  Adedayo 
>  Prince of Nigeria

In my solution I can't see any reference to palindromes and I can't explain the given numbers. 
First I use

> Rot20 (i.e. a->u, b->v, g->a etc.).

Then the text is readable yet. After that I

> swap some characters again: a->#, g->a, f->g, x->d, e->f, b->e, #->b

Alternatively you can decrypt in one step by using following table

> `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` 
>  `UVWDYZBECDFGAHIJKLMNOPQRST` 
>  Note that `D` appears twice.

OP Edit:

> To solve this puzzle, you can also do the following:
> You should notice that the two stanzas and the numbers are both palindromes, and they both contain six of them each. This is the displacement you need to know for the Caesar cipher. (I did an offset of six, but I guess it went the other way, hence the shift of 20).
> You should then follow the operator's directions, to end up with a number of 7134, which you should translate to the letters gacd. This is the keyword shift.
> Finally, you'll arrive at the answer, where instead of starting with Dear, it'll be Xear (our friend from Nigeria's native language isn't English)

Comment: I mean, you're not wrong, but I'm disappointed that you didn't find out the clues. Not only was it a Caesar cipher, but also a keyword cipher. If you can tell me that, I'll accept this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Well, that's a common problem with cipher puzzles: even if you use a Caesar shift and a keyed alphabet, you still have a monoalphabetic substitution, which is [easy to crack](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/caesar-keyed.php). You've worked in ingenious clues to the key, but the sily solver just finds the solution anyway. Here, you use a [keyed Caesar](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/caesar-keyed.php) with a shift of 20 and the key "becdfga". The key uses only the letters a-g, which means anything from h on is just Caesar.

Comment: The palindromes are easy to spot and the numbers are [palindromes, too](https://oeis.org/A007632). I guess the first elements of that series must be used to generate the key, but I can't see how.

Comment: You can avoid the problems of monoalphabetic ciphers by using a many-to-one relationship where one letter may be encoded in several ways, as in [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42015/an-encoded-message-for-nigel), for example.

Comment: @MOehm, thanks, I'll consider that for future puzzles.

Comment: Your hint are 5 operators. Together with these 6 numbers I get 7134 or in letters "gacd". This is not the keyword. I'm afraid I don't get your clues yet.

Comment: But if I take the sum of digits of the 6 numbers and then apply these operators, I get 42. That's an answer!

Comment: @VV5198722, actually, that was indeed the keyword, when combined with the shift, you'd arrive at the answer. You'd need to use the Ceasar cipher first, then the keyword cipher. The Caesar cipher is found by recognizing the patterns of the palindromes.